# Default shortcut for Replace-Next in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

Regardless of whether it were supposedly possible to customize this shortcut in the user preferences file (*) : is there actually a *default* shortcut for Replace/Replace-Next ?   Following shows there is no hover-help on it:

[image]

(*) After many attempts I have never been successful for the `keymap.cson` to be respected by Atom. It just gets ignored. Thus I want to use whatever is the default binding for Replace[/-Next] .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no *default* shortcut for "Replace Next", only one for "Replace All" (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>).

But there is a built-in command for it. Putting this in my `keymap.cson` file works for me:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'alt-cmd-e': 'find-and-replace:replace-next'
```

I found this example from here:
https://github.com/bronson/dotfiles/blob/master/.atom/keymap.cson

All of the default settings are here:
https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/blob/master/keymaps/find-and-replace.cson

It sounds like you already know this, but just for reference, you can find your `keymap.cson` file by going to Settings (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>), and clicking the "Open Config Folder" button.

If your `keymap.cson` is being ignored, I would start to diagnose the problem by commenting out everything except those two lines in order to see if another setting in `keymap.cson` is broken.

Comment: Is there a "skip"?   I'd like to be able to either skip or accept replacement via keystrokes

Comment: Yup. That's the `find-and-replace:find-next` command. You can find it under Settings > Keybindings or in the second link I just added. It's `f3` on Windows/Linux and `⌘+g` on Mac.